# Retrieve more than 2500 records from a DE using SSJS

Tags: dataextensions, ssjs, marketing-cloud

Trying to retrieve more than 2500 records from a DE. My thought is to have a for loop (to process the recordset) within a while loop (to retrieve records).

```
var data;
var recordCount = 0;

do {    
    data = rDE.Rows.Retrieve(complexfilter);
    recordCount = data.length;

    for( i = 0; i < recordCount; i++) {
        var rLeadId = data[i].LeadId;
        Write(i + " : " + rLeadId + "<br/>")
    }
} while (recordCount > 0)
```

The error is:

```
throw "There was an error retrieving the rows."
```

Comment: related to:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167801/ssjs-retrieve-dataextension-rows-by-retrieverequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process does work. I was forgetting to update the data so the complexfilter would return a new dataset.

Comment: Hi! I would like to know if this limitation still exists as I am facing a similar problem with SSJS. I have elaborated more here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274369/always-2500-rows-found-in-the-filter So I am wondering if adding the do-while loop to your code solved your problem. Thank you for your time in advance!